# Transparent Context in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm displaying an image in a `UIScrollView` but I want it to blend with a `UIImageView` which is laid behind the `UIScrollView`.

I'm currently trying to override - `(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` in a subclass of `UIView` created to display the image inside the scrollview, using either the method `drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:` or `CGContextSetBlendMode` but none worked. I think the reason is that the current context is opaque but I cannot find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can add UIImageView as a subclass of UIView (parent view of your scroll view).
You can change opacity of your UIImageView to match your criteria. If you just want a image as a background of your UIView you can set up background of your view and as a colour you can use `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:Your UIImage here]`.
Is it something you need?

//EXTENDED

I try it and both of the example below set the image as a background and when I scroll the image is not moving:

Example 1:

```
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newtons_cradle.jpg"]]];
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 1000.0f)];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 50)];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setText:@"Label Test Text"];
    [scrollView addSubview:label];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Example 2:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newtons_cradle.jpg"]];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 1000.0f)];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 50)];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setText:@"Label Test Text"];
[scrollView addSubview:label];

[self.view addSubview:scrollView]
```

;

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that the image inside a view won't blend in the background of any of its parent views and setting the background image as the background of the image inside the UIScrollView won't prevent it from moving around when scrolling.

Comment: Yes, they won't move that way but they won't blend with the content of my UIScrollView either, which is my main goal.